# Laravel 5 Class 'Category' not found

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I've installed Baum on laravel 5 and ran `php artisan baum:install Category`, which created *Category* class that look like this:

```
<?php
use Baum\Node;

class Category extends Node {
}
```

When I try to run:

```
$root = Category::create(['name' => 'Root category'])
```

I get the error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Class 'Category' not found
```

I ran `composer dump-autoload`, but it did not help.

Comment: Did you add 'use Category;' in the file where you see/call Category? Also if you haven't added namespace into your Category file it's assumed it is in App folder by laravel...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your declaration need to set the namespace.

```
<?php
namespace App; // use your app namespace
use Baum\Node;

class Category extends Node {
}
```

when you'll run, you can use full namespace call or with 'use' stat.

```
$root = App\Category::create(['name' => 'Root category']);
```

or

```
use App\Category;

$root = Category::create(...);
```